# Python Multiprocessing, Need to Give Extra Arguement

Tags: python, arguments, multiprocessing

In Python, what do you do if you are using a multiprocessing and you need to give the function an extra agruement?

Example:

```
if value == "Y":
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=8)
        pool.map(verify_headers, url_list)<-need to give parameter for a password
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print "Done..."
```

and the function would be something like:

```
def verify_headers(url, password):
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

`Pool.map` takes a function of one argument and an iterable to produce that argument.  We can turn your function of two arguments into a function of one argument by wrapping it in another function body:

```
def verify_headers_with_passowrd(url):
    return verify_headers(url, 'secret_password')
```

And pass that to `pool.map` instead:

```
pool.map(verify_headers_with_password, url_list)
```

so long as `verify_headers` can take `password` as a keyword argument, we can shorten that a little: you can use `functools.partial`

```
pool.map(functools.partial(verify_headers, password='secret_password'), url_list)
```

Edit: as `Bakuriu` points out, `multiprocessing` passes data round by pickling, so the following *doesn't* work:

```
pool.map(lambda url: verify_headers(url, 'secret_password'), url_list)
```

Since lambda's are functions without a name, and pickle serialzes functions by name.

Comment: Thanks. With having a wrapped function return the inner function to the multiprocessing call will the inner function still be ran in true multiprocessing?

Comment: yep,  nothing special going on here.

Answer (score 1):

i believe

```
from functools import partial
```

and

```
pool.map(partial(verify_headers,password=password),url_list)
```

should work?

edit: fixed based on recommendations below

Comment: nnnot quite;  `partial` can't insert positional arguments in the front.

Comment: Now the code makes sense, but it still wont work due to pickling errors.

Comment: @Bakuriu Thanks for the info, I didn't realize multiprocessing worked that way

Answer (score 0):

You define a function, right after the original, that accepts as argument a 2-element tuple:

```
def verify_headers_tuple(url_passwd):
    return verify_headers(*url_passwd)
```

Then you can `zip` the original `url_list` with `itertools.repeat(password)`:

```
pool.map(verify_headers_tuple, it.izip(url_list, it.repeat(password)))
```

---

Note that the function passed to `Pool.map` *must* be defined at the top level of a module(due to pickling restrictions), which means you cannot use `partial` or `lambda` to create a "curried function".

Comment: It seems like pickle support for `partial` was added in 2009: http://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/184ca6293218/  Unfortunately, it seems like the change was never backported to 2.6, so it only works for 2.7 and above.